# Filter ActiveRecord objects based on model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

Is there a way to use a filter criterion in `where`, which is not a DB column. If I have a `Movie` model with the following method:

```
def blockbuster?
  imdb_rating > 8
end
```

is there a way to do something like `Movie.where(:blockbuster? => true)`. I know that in this particular example it's possible to just use the `imdb_rating` attribute (`Movie.where('imdb_rating > ?', 8)`), but there are cases, when a method does a more complex logic. Currently, if I want to do this, I must call `Movie.all.select(&:blockbuster?)`, but I want to do this at the DB level. Thank you.

P.S. I am sure that similar questions are asked many times, but I can't seem to think of the right keywords to find them here or on Google. Please, post a link if this is answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making it into a scope? There is some information on scopes [in the Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope).

Basically, with your method, you'd do something like:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :blockbuster, -> { where('imdb_rating > ?', 8) }
end

Movie.blockbuster # returns all relevant objects as an ActiveRecord relation
```

Class methods are also available as scopes:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.blockbuster?
    where('imdb_rating ?', 8)
  end
end

Movie.blockbuster? # also returns all relevant objects as an ActiveRecord relation
```

Comment: No, the whole point is I don't use the contents of the method. Imagine a method that is provided by an external gem. The point is - I don't touch the object attributes/table columns directly.

Comment: boolean methods should be for methods returning booleans ;)